# Do negative reputation changes affect the epic/legendary badge progress

Tags: discussion, daily-reputation-badges

Does negative reputation (unupvotes, downvotes, downvoting an answer, user removed, starting a bounty) affect the progress for the daily reputation badges (epic/legendary) or does just the "positive" reputation count?

For example, say I get 20 upvotes in one day and receive one downvote, does it count as +1 progress for these badges or do I have to have at least +200 **net reputation** (21 upvotes + 1 downvote) in one day?

It's hard to keep track of that manually because I have to be online just at the right moment at the right circumstances so I thought it might be worthwhile to ask if someone knows or had looked at the right moment and place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only positive reputation events, excluding the association bonus, are looked at when determining the Legendary family of badges. Downvotes do not matter at all.

However, any events that have since been reversed do not count on *either* day. So in the case of a removed upvote, the unupvote event for today will not play into the badge, but the upvote from the previous day will also stop playing into the badge. So it is possible that a day that previously counted will stop counting towards the badge in the future.

Comment: Interesting and thanks for the answer! Just one minor follow-up: In case of an un-upvotes will another (not counted because reputation cap was already reached) upvote replace the undone upvote? I mean: Count towards my reputation and the legendary-like-badges-progress? Or should I ask another question about that (couldn't find any Q+A on that)?

Comment: If one was capped, the recalc would count that upvote instead, yes.

Comment: @animuson Ok, now you got me curious. Lets say that on a particular day I get exactly 20 upvotes (200 rep) and cap out and get awarded the badge for doing that (however many times).  Then two days later one of those votes is retracted, reducing the rep total for the day to 190. Do I lose the badge?

Comment: @Draco18s We only retract tag badges. All others, once you have it, there is no process that ever takes it away.

Comment: @animuson Good to know. I'm sure it hardly ever comes up, but I was curious (curiosity kills more than cats you know, and dragons are just large scaly cats...)

Comment: hi @animuson, you can probably confirm or correct what I said here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/376997/how-does-accept-unaccept-affect-epic-and-legendary-badge-progress?cb=1 .. almost similar question to this one.