# How does accept + unaccept affect Epic and Legendary badge progress?

Tags: discussion, badge-progress, daily-reputation-badges

I am wondering if the following scenarios count toward [Epic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/145/epic) and [Legendary](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/146/legendary) badge progress:

#### Accept followed by Unaccept

- 190 points at some point in day
- Answer is accepted (205 points)
- Answer is unaccepted a few minutes later (190 points)
- Day ends

#### Upvote followed by Unupvote

- 190 points at some point in day
- Answer is upvoted (200 points)
- Answer is unupvoted few minutes later (190 points)
- Day ends

There could be other cases (bounty, user removed, etc.), but the crux of the question is: can I go to sleep after touching 200+ points?

PS: an answer to a similar question suggests that negative reputation changes are not counted. However, it is unclear if unaccept is counted as negative reputation (a -15 that is independent of the +15) or treated as if it never existed (both +15 and -15 are removed from the system).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Undone votes are not considered negative reputation events. A retraction of a previous event is very different than an event that causes negative reputation. A retracted vote essentially **deletes** the original vote as if it never existed and the events in your reputation history only exist for accounting purposes. While those retraction events won't affect your reputation thresholds for the day when the retraction occurred, if it causes you to fall below the threshold on the day where the original vote occurred (because it is no longer counted) then **that day will stop counting towards your overall progress**. This will not immediately reflect in your badge progress because it is not recalculated in real-time.

Only currently active, non-deleted votes are considered when counting days towards the badges.

Comment: In Nov 13, I have reached +200 then deleted an upvoted answer (which is a retracted event I suppose) but it was still counted towards the progress badge as if I reached the cap. I am following the legendary badge progress and I didn't notice any minus but considering your answer I should have a -1, so why that?

Comment: @TemaniAfif I don't know how often the system recalculates badge progress, but it won't be counted in the real badge checks.

Comment: I have a theory and wondering if someone could confirm it. I believe the badge progress counter does not go back once the progress has "settled in". My progress according to [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/994408/more-accurate-epic-legendary-badge-progress) is lower than what is displayed on badge progress. I also cross checked by parsing the information on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation)... it confirms that retracted votes are not counted on either day but the number of 200s is less than the progress shown on badge.

Answer (score 10):

I think you can go to sleep after seeing `200+` even if you get unaccepted, un-upvote, user removed, offered a bounty, etc... It happened to me and I didn't lost the progress of the legendary/epic badge.

What I noticed is that you need to reach (even for few minutes) `200+` considering all the positive scores (don't consider the negative ones). So you can increase the progress of the badge by only having `+150` for example (`+200` and `-50`).

You can also check this link https://stackoverflow.com/reputation for your reputation recap. You will notice at the end: `earned at least 200 reputation on X days`. The `X` will probably be smaller than the number of days shown in the badge progress (`Y/150`).

I have 12 days of difference (`Y - X`) which means that I have reached an overall of `+200`  without keeping them or I have reached a positive score of `+200`.

Example of day (`+245` `-70`):

> [image]

Another example of day where I have reached `+200` as positive score for a short period of time (*[I deleted an upvoted question (`+20`)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53290329/8620333)*).

> [image]

Concerning your last question, It will depend if both actions are made in the same day or not. I had an accepted answer that got unaccepted another day so both `+15` and `-15` exist in different days and logically affect the reputation of each day:

> [image]

If both happen the same day then both will not be visible in your reputation (probably treated as never existed) BUT the `+15` will affect the reputation for the badge progress if it allow you to go past `+200` before the unaccept action.

So *probably* you can earn the legendary badge with `0` reputation:

1. You get 14 accepted answers (`+210`).
2. The progress of the badge will increment.
3. Right after you get unaccepted (you fall back to `0`).

You repeat this each day.

<sup>This is **my own** analysis based on what I noticed and what happened to me so I may be wrong in some cases.</sup>

Comment: All true. Except that nobody hunting the legendary badge can sleep well. It starts eating up your soul at some point :-o